# How to generate a list of shuffled arrays from a given array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, shuffle

I look to the internet for this issue and found that I can use the random_shuffle function from `<algorithm>` header. My following code:

```
void Localization::generate_population(){
    int* ptr = new int[size];
    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i) ptr[i] = i;

    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i) {
        std::random_shuffle(ptr, ptr + size);
        population[i] = ptr;
    }
}
```

This is my class function which is automatically called in the constructor. I'd ran the program and end up with the same shuffled arrays. The internet told me that I forgot to add `std::srand(std::time(0))` at the beginning of my program, so I did just that:

**I'd removed some code to make it easier to read. Hopefully it is still understandable.**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    Localization* gps = new Localization(array_here);
    delete gps;
}
```

However, when I build and ran my program I get a similar result:

```
[ INFO] [1630975155.983523195]: 0: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.983979451]: 1: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.983990418]: 2: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.983996142]: 3: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.984001312]: 4: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.984006477]: 5: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
[ INFO] [1630975155.984013677]: 6: [2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 3]
```

Not exactly sure how `std::srand(std::time(0))` works, but maybe it is because the for loop ran too fast for the `std::srand(std::time(0))` to take any effect. Is there a better way to shuffle the array in my situation?

Edited code (worked but not sure if it is efficient):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main(){
    int size {5};
    int** a2d = new int*[size]; 
    int* ptr = new int[size];
    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i) ptr[i] = i;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine dre{ rd() }; 
    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i){
        int* another = new int[size];
        std::copy(ptr, ptr + size, another);
        std::shuffle(another, another + size, dre);
        a2d[i] = another;
        std::copy(another, another + size, ptr);
    }
    delete ptr;

    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%d: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, a2d[i][0], a2d[i][1], a2d[i][2], a2d[i][3], a2d[i][4]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: 3, 2, 4, 0, 1
1: 0, 1, 3, 4, 2
2: 4, 3, 1, 2, 0
3: 3, 2, 0, 1, 4
4: 0, 4, 2, 1, 3
```

Comment: `random_shuffle` has been deprecated. Try `shuffle` instead.

Comment: `std::time` has a resolution of 1 second so if you run your program a bunch of times during the same second, you get the same seed, so you get the same "random" result. `srand` and `rand` suck (and by extension, `std::shuffle` which is deprecated). Use the new `<random>` features ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)).

Comment: All `population`'s elements point on the same pointer... using `std::vector` would allow to have true copy (without to have to handle memory manually).

Comment: You might avoid to use `new`, `Localization gps(array_here);` would be enough in `main`. `std::vector`/`std::array` for the different numbers lists.

Answer (score 2):

As @cigien commented, `random_shuffle` has been deprecated. You can use the standard "shuffle" function which shuffles all the elements of a given container.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine dre{ rd() }; // seed RNG

std::shuffle(std::begin(myContainer), std::end(myContainer), dre);
```

Comment: Note that while this approach is definitely better than the one in the question there aren't strict requirements for `std::random_device` to be actually random. On some platforms, it can be the same sequence of bytes every execution. *"std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each std::random_device object may generate the same number sequence."* But most of the time, it is non-deterministic.

Comment: @spitconsumer Hello, I edited my post and use your method, but likely in a very inefficient way in order to satisfy my needs. I couldn't think of a better way to do this and likely won't switch to vectors because I will end up having to go through another year of painstakingly debugging the program just for this "rather simple" task. Any suggestions?

Comment: Who said anything about vectors? You can use standard algorithm with pointers. Got a pointer to an array of ten integers you want to sort? `std::sort(myPointer, myPointer+10);` And yeah, don't worry, it is efficient. Standard containers and functions are basically the best you can get. You can only get better with stuff that wouldn't be portable, I could only assume. Use what's available. Don't reinvent the wheel.